# How can I decide Rebuilding Index with DETAILED or SAMPLED on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2012

I want to rebuild my indexes and statistics on DB.

How can I select this option on production maintenance.

SQL Server Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @erhun Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: This blogpost contains the scripts and maintainance plan http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1367/sql-server-script-to-rebuild-all-indexes-for-all-tables-and-all-databases/, it will be useful for you.

Comment: Consider using Ola Hallengren's maintance scripts:  https://ola.hallengren.com/.  These are easy to use and powerful.

Comment: I agree with @dan. For the "accidental DBA", Ola's scripts are a godsend. Heck, even for me (16 year professional), I still go to them first before I ever consider creating my own... or worse yet, relying on MS's built in maintenance plans <<shudder>>.

Comment: I agree with Dan and chris, Ola is really the way to go if you have a database which is small to normal size. For a really big database with huge tables (100 - 200 GB data) Ola will not suffice.  So my question is how big is your database?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to rebuild the indexes where the fragmentation percent of the indexes is greater than 30% and a Re-org of indexes where fragmentation percent is in between 9% and 30%.

Coming to update stats, I would prefer to do it with Full Scan depending on the size of the databases.

While these are resource intensive database operations, I would prefer to do these operations over the weekends or after business hours.

For Production Environments, I would usually setup jobs and allow them to run over the weekend.

Please go through the below link for maintenance plans(very useful) and customize accordingly to your environment.

https://ola.hallengren.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would go with detailed if it finishes in a timely basis. I run a check index statistics script every night and if it can rebuild within the time allocated for low activity I would go with detailed because the resulting statistics seem to produce better query plans.